# how to determine if points is on shape and in shape?

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

I have two of this:

```
bool isPointOnShape(int a, int b)
{

}

bool isPointInShape(int a, int b)
{

}
```

Say I have a square, first point (bottom left corner) is x,y (0,0) second point (top left) is (0,2), third is (2,2) and fourth is (0,2).

The Points on shape would be (0,1) (1,2) (2,1) (1,0) and Points in shape is (1,1)

How do I find out the points on shape / in shape and return a true value so that I can store it somewhere?

Comment: The point `{1, 1}` is not the only one *in shape*. Why that precisely? Also the method to find this point is clearly dependent on the type or shape and on its parameters, where do you get those informations?

Comment: Are these raster points, i.e. pixels?

Answer (score 1):

For a potentially non-convex shape you may use an algorithm like this:

1. Find how many shape edges intersect a ray starting at `(a,b)`. You may choose any ray, but it is easier to calculate intersections if the ray is horizontal or vertical.
2. Point is inside if the number of intersections is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Try going over this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html) in openCV explaining how to use the **point in polygon test**. Also a good reference is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) wiki page which covers several other methods.

If you don't want to use openCV - in general you can use the Ray casting algorithm:

1. take a line from the given point `(x,y)` in any direction you want, let's call it `L`
2. for each line in `((0,0),(0,2)), ((0,0),(2,0)), ((2,2),(0,2)), ((2,2),(2,0))` test if that line intersect with with `L` and count the number of intersections `N`
3. if `N` is odd the point `(x,y)` is in the polygon